# can't print extracted xml content with karate

Tags: testing, mocking, karate

Im trying to print a value I've extracted from an xml file. i know i can compare with method **bodyPath** but why i can't print the value I've found e.g

```js
* def username = bodyPath('/Envelope/Body/Users/Username')
* print username
```

for some reason this doesn't work. is it a compare to return true or false only? or can i also use it for to get a value from an xml file?

Comment: Maybe your XPath is wrong. What happens if you print `request` ? If you do that, you may get some ideas.

Comment: this is what im getting back "com.intuit.karate - [print]"

Comment: but i can successfully print request

Comment: then you should be able to now figure what to do. else please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: XPath is correct because i can compare and it works ----> Scenario: pathMatches('/example/v4') bodyPath('/Envelope/Body/Users/Username') == 'somName'    this work, but i can't print the value

Comment: i've decided to use this method karate.xmlPath(data,path) as opposed to the one above. seems like like they are different in terms of function.

Comment: I believe they are the same, so it would be great if you could give me a way to replicate so that I can fix anything if needed and update the documentation

Comment: the issue is that i was doing this on Background instead of Scenario. you were right they do work the same. but now question is whats the purpose of Background?

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#background